# Creating a proper knapsack logic on objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, knapsack-problem

i had this knapsack logic code working on my app but if the array is too big, i will get `exc_bad_access code=2` often on the C array and i couldn't find why and hope you guys can enlighten me what went wrong on my code.

```
//main chunk of code for Knapsack logic
-(NSMutableArray* )knapsackWithWeightArray:(NSMutableArray*)weightArray andLimits:(NSInteger)WLimits
{
    NSMutableArray *keepSongs = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:WLimits];//array to keep songs
    NSInteger N = [weightArray count]; // number of items
    NSInteger option[N+1][WLimits+1];  // opt[n][w] = max profit of packing items 1..n with weight limit w
    bool sol[N+1][WLimits+1];  //does opt solution to pack items 1..n with weight limit w include item n?
    NSInteger totalDuration = 0;
    for (NSInteger n = 1; n<= N; n++) // no of items
    {
        for (NSInteger w = 1; w <= WLimits; w++) // loop for weights
        {
            WeightObject *wObj = weightArray[n-1];
            NSInteger opt1 = option[n-1][w]; // crash here
            NSInteger opt2 = INT32_MIN;
            NSInteger knWeight = wObj.weight;

            if (knWeight <= w)
            {
                opt2 = wObj.Value + option[n-1][w - knWeight]; // crash here
            }
            // select better of two options
            option[n][w] = MAX(opt1, opt2); // crash here
            sol[n][w] = opt2 > opt1; // ensure opt & sol same size. // crash here
        }
    }

    // determine which items to take
    for (NSInteger n = N, w = WLimits; n > 0; n--)
    {
        if (sol[n][w])
        {
            w = w - [weightArray[n-1]weight];
            WeightObject *obj = weightArray[n-1];
            totalDuration = totalDuration + obj.weight;
            [keepSongs addObject:obj.songObj];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"knapsackWithWeightArray totalDuration %d",totalDuration);
    return keepSongs;
}
```

Comment: How big is "too big"?  At what size array does it work and at what size array does it break?

Comment: @nhgrif the count always shows n=931

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by change the C array to Obj C array

```
//main chunk of code for Knapsack logic
-(NSMutableArray* )knapsackWithWeightArray:(NSMutableArray*)weightArray andLimits:(NSInteger)WLimits
{
    NSMutableArray *keepSongs = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:WLimits];
    NSInteger N = [weightArray count]-1; // number of items
    NSMutableArray *optionA = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:(N+1)]; //first []
    NSMutableArray *solA = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:(N+1)]; //first []

    for (NSInteger i=0; i<(N+1); i++)
    {
        optionA[i] = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:WLimits + 1];//init second []
        solA[i] = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:WLimits + 1]; //init second []

        for (NSInteger j=0; j<(WLimits+1); j++)
        {
            optionA[i][j] = @0; //fill with zero
            solA[i][j] = @0; //fill with zero
        }
    }

    NSInteger totalDuration = 0;

    for (NSInteger n = 1; n<= N; n++) // no of items
    {
        for (NSInteger w = 1; w <= WLimits; w++) // loop for weights etc 900
        {
            WeightObject *wObj = weightArray[n-1];
            //don't take item n
            //NSInteger opt1 = option[n-1][w];
            NSInteger opt1 = [optionA[n-1][w] integerValue];
            NSInteger opt2 = INT32_MIN;

            // take item n
            NSInteger knWeight = wObj.weight;//[weightArray[n-1]weight];

            if (knWeight <= w)
            {
                //opt2 = [weightArray[n-1]Value] + option[n-1][w - knWeight];
                opt2 = wObj.Value + [optionA[n-1][w - knWeight] integerValue];
            }
            // select better of two options
            optionA[n][w] = @(MAX(opt1, opt2));
            //sol[n][w] = opt2 > opt1; // ensure opt & sol same size.
            solA[n][w] = @(opt2 > opt1);
        }
    }

    // determine which items to take
    for (NSInteger n = N, w = WLimits; n > 0; n--)
    {
        if ([solA[n][w]boolValue])
        {
            w = w - [weightArray[n-1]weight];
            WeightObject *obj = weightArray[n-1];
            totalDuration = totalDuration + obj.weight;
            [keepSongs addObject:obj.songObj];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"knapsackWithWeightArray totalDuration %d",totalDuration);
    return keepSongs;
}
```